# Google CSE limit indexing of single file?

Tags: pdf, google-custom-search

I have been using Google CSE to index several long PDF files for searching (some 500+ pages long). I am noticing that the search will find terms close to the beginning of some of these documents, but not terms that are near the end of the document. Is there a limit to how much of a single file Google will index?

Answer (score 0):

Since no one seems to know, I will provide my experience. We have requested a manual index of the pdf files several times, and still cannot get the search to pick up any search terms past page 10-15. It seems like there is a character limit on how much of a single pdf gets indexed. Google support is not available to confirm this until the business version is purchased, which we won't be doing.